# undefined method `model_path' for #<#<Class:> UPDATE method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, form-for

I'am getting this error:

```
undefined method `invite_path' for #<#<Class:0x9396d38>:0x8f8fb30>
```

**My controller**

```
class ConfirmationsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

  def index
    @confirmation = Invite.joins(:user).select('invites.horario_desde, invites.horario_hasta, invites.estado, users.email, users.nombre, users.apellido, users.telefono, invites.complejo')
      .where(:hash_id => filter_params[:hash_id],:user_id => filter_params[:user_id]).first
  end
```

(it gets only one record)

**My Routes**

```
  get '/confirmations' => 'confirmations#index'
  post '/confirmations' => 'confirmations#update'
```

**And my view**

```
<%= form_for @confirmation do |confirmation|%>
  <p>Horario: de <%= confirmation.horario_desde %> a <%= confirmation.horario_hasta %></p>
  <p>Email: <%= confirmation.email %></p>
  <p>Teléfono: <%= confirmation.telefono %></p>

  <%=f.submit 'Confirm'%>
  <%=f.submit 'Cancel'%>
<%end%>
```

The idea is to show some data from my controller (@confirmations) and if the user clicks "confirm" should **update** my model with a particular status. But I'm not even able to make this form works.

Is there another better way?

Thanks

Comment: It's normally a bad idea to be overly specific with `select`, it's safer to use `includes` to join in associated models. I think your non-standard model instance is confusing `form_for`.

Answer (score 1):

The error appear because the form action using `@confirmation` object from controller. You can use [Resource-oriented style](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for-label-Resource-oriented+style)

Try to run `rake routes` at your project directory, you can see some alias each route.

example :

```
confirmations    GET        /confirmations(.:format)          confirmations#index
confirmations    POST        /confirmations(.:format)          confirmations#update
```

Use alias path to your form action, something like this

```
<%= form_for @confirmation, url: confirmations_path(@confirmation) do |confirmation|%>
  <%# .... another stuff here ... %>
<% end %>
```

note : `confirmations_path` just an example.

Comment: is not working :( Now im getting an error when it tries to read the @confirmation attribute> undefined method `field' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x5658f00>. I know this object has something in it. If a take away the form it works..

Comment: @EzequielRamiro that problem in your form but I can't see `field` method in your form

Comment: Is it safe to set it to `confirmations_path(nil)`? In my situation, it is only an email contact form, now show or index needs.

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across to this problem. The issue in your case is you are using the form for the `invite` path for the post action. Since there is no routes to handle the problem, You are getting an error.

There are two ways to handle the problem:

1. Add the path in the routes.

   `post 'invite', to: 'invite#create'`
2. Adding the resources to the `invite` in the routes

   `resources :invite`

This will create handlers for `new, edit, update, show, destroy`. If you want 
 any specific operation, then try like

```
  `resources :invite, except: [:update]`
```

Hope it helps :)